# Why is Spring logging the ResponseStatusException exception stack trace even though the exception has been handled?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, error-handling

I have a codebase that has 2 layers, the controller and service layer, and if an unrecoverable error occurs, like an entity cannot be found, I throw a ResponseStatusException with HTTP status code 404 from the service layer.

I also have a controller advice that has an ExceptionHandler for the ResponseStatusException that creates a custom response and sends it.

So the exception is perfectly handled, however I still get stack traces in my log like this:

```
2023-11-07T08:38:23.763+01:00 ERROR 2618932 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] org.example.ExampleResource   : Exception in exampleMethod() with cause = 'NULL' and exception = '404 NOT_FOUND "dd"'

org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException: 404 NOT_FOUND "entity not found!"
    at org.example.ExampleResource.exampleMethod(ExampleResource.java:81) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
```

My controller advice exception handler looks like this:

```
    @ResponseBody
    @ExceptionHandler(value = {ResponseStatusException.class})
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> responseStatusExceptionHandler(ResponseStatusException exception,
                                                                    WebRequest request) {
        return handleExceptionInternal(exception,
                buildResponseBody(exception.getReason(), request, httpCodeToStatus(exception.getStatusCode())), new HttpHeaders(),
                exception.getStatusCode(), request);
    }
```

Also, note that the stack trace log level is ERROR, so why is this happening if I have it handled?

Comment: Is it possible your application server always logs when it sends a 404?

Comment: It logs regardless of HTTP status code. 

EDIT: I read again the stack trace and found out what is the issue, it is here: 

`at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]` and the keyword is 'aop'...


I have an aspect logger set up and I had it log after throwing, I feel so stupid now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
```

The keyword is 'aop', there is an aspect logger set up so it logs after every throw, regardless if the throw has been handled by the ControllerAdvice.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).